# JQuery - Iterate over a subset of tds starting after a found class

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a more jquery/cleaner way to be able to select all `td.some-class` and be able to start at 'selected' and apply some in order to the tds that follow.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='some-class'>A</td>
    <td class='some-class'>B</td>
    <td class='some-class'>C</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='some-class'>A1</td>
    <td class='some-class'>B2</td>
    <td class='some-class selected'>C3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='some-class'>A21</td>
    <td class='some-class'>B22</td>
    <td class='some-class'>C23</td>
 </tr>
```

The current way I am doing it is pretty much like:

```
found = false;
$('td.some-class').each(function(){

     if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){
        found  = true;
     }
     if (found){
           # do something
     }
});
```

Comment: why not using `$('td.some-class .selected')....$(this).next()` directly

Comment: Have you tried $("td.some-class .selected")?

Comment: I want to process them in order starting at selected... ? next() will break once I hit a tr..

Comment: So if C3 is selected, a21, b22, c23 should also get some jquery?

Comment: Yes.  I want to process any td after selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My try(it's a litte more efficient then @suhair answer):

```
var all = $('#xTable .some-class');
var selected = all.filter('.selected')[0];
var selectedIndex = all.index(selected);
var after = all.filter(':gt(' + selectedIndex + ')');
```

@suhair [**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vY3s/2/)

[JSperf](http://jsperf.com/select-next-elems-after-selected)

Comment: @Nix.  It's my favorite as well... **:-)** thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

This is my quick try on [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/NeFjK/)

```
var index = $('#xTable td').index($("#xTable td.selected"));    
$('#xTable td:gt('+ index+')').css("border", "1px solid red");
```

Hope this is what you intended

Comment: **+1** you might wanna look at my try.